# Using different API for different Windows versions efficiently

Tags: c, windows, winapi, dll

I'm faced with the need to use a new Windows runtime function where it's available, and fall back to an older one where the new one doesn't exist.

The code path is performance-critical. I need to call `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` if the platform (Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012) offers it, and fall back to `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` if the newer version doesn't exist.

I'm aware that I can use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to load `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` and if that fails, fall back to `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`. I'm concerned about the performance impact of calling something as performance-criticial as this though another layer of indirection though.

Is there any built-in mechanism to lazy load a symbol, not a whole DLL? So I can test the Windows version at startup and call a function that uses `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` on Win8, otherwise call the one that uses `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`, without causing the whole executable to fail with a link error on older Windows versions?

Or should I just stop worrying and use `GetProcAddress`?

Comment: I'd say "don't worry and use GetProcAddress". The additional indirection is probably very small.

Comment: Try stepping into the GetSystemTimeAsFileTime, once with GetProcAddr and once without, there is probably barely a difference.

Comment: There is no "layer of indirection".  Otherwise something that a profiler or a little test program can easily show you.

Comment: You need at most two calls to GetProcAddress. Why are you concerned about the performance of a function call that you make twice at startup and never run again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the various comments to the question say, the cost of `GetProcAddress()` is minimal. The cost of calling a function via a function pointer is also near-zero.

But let's say we're working hyper-critically. We observe that the two functions that you want to call have the signatures

```
VOID WINAPI GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(LPFILETIME lpSystemTimeAsFileTime);
void WINAPI GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(LPFILETIME lpSystemTimeAsFileTime);
```

That is, they have nearly the same signatures; the only difference is that weird return type of `VOID`... [which MSDN says is just a macro that expands to `void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so they're exactly the same.

What does this mean? This means you can use a single function pointer variable, initialized once at the start of your program like so:

```
// global scope
VOID (*WINAPI myGetSystemTime)(LPFILETIME);

// in your initalization code
FARPROC fp;
myGetSystemTime = GetSystemTimeAsFileTime;
if (/* LoadLibraryW(L"kernel32.dll") worked */) {
    fp = GetProcAddress(/* library handle */, "GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime");
    if (fp != NULL)
        myGetSystemTime = (VOID (*WINAPI)(LPFILETIME)) fp;
}
// and don't worry about errors from LoadLibraryW() or GetProcAddress() since we want to use the fallback; you may log a warning if you so choose
```

and then all you need to do is call `(*myGetSystemTime)(&time)` when you need to selectively call the function. No conditional branches or constantly polling DLLs, and there should be no measurable performance impact.

Comment: And if the signatures were different you could put a wrapper function around them, and store the pointer to *that*.

Answer (score 4):

I think andlabs answer is probably right; the performance loss from calling a function via a pointer is unlikely to be significant.  On the other hand, it does require an additional round-trip to RAM (or else causes the pointer to take up a line in the cache that might be better used) so it isn't *absolutely* certain.

If profiling demonstrates that you really do have a problem, consider putting the performance-critical code into a DLL.  Have two versions of the DLL, one for each of the APIs.  When your application is installed, put the appropriate version in place.